# Bitonic Sort (Calculating complexity)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

so basically I'm trying to understand how a time complexity of Bitonic Sort should be calculated and best and worse case scenarios decided using Cost and Time and then adding and multiplying values.

As an example: I tried first calculating complexity of Insertion sort.

```
        void sort(int A[]){                             Cost        Time

        for (int i = 1; i < A.length; i++)              c1          n
        {
            int key = A[i];                             c2          n-1
            int j = i-1;                                c3          n-1
            while (j >= 0 && A[j] > key){               c4          Σ (j=2 to n) of t_j
                A[j+1] = A[j];                          c5          Σ (j=2 to n) of (t_j-1)
                j = j-1;                                c6          Σ (j=2 to n) of (t_j-1)
            }
            A[j+1] = key;                               c7          n-1
        }
    }
```

t_j - is the amount of times "while" cycle is executed.

T(n) = c1*n + c2(n-1) + c3(n-1) + c4(Σ (j=2 to n) of t_j) +

+c5(Σ (j=2 to n) of (t_j-1)) +
c6(Σ (j=2 to n) of (t_j-1)) + c7(n-1)

So in best case scenario t_j = 1, then: T(n) = an + b; (a, b - constants)

In worst case scenario t_j = j, then:   T(n) = an^2 + bn + c;

So - O(n) - best case? O(n^2) - worse case ?

However I do not really understand what should be the cost and time of operations of bitonic sort methods and such, for example of the code like this:

```
   public class BitonicSorter implements Sorter
{
    private int[] a;
    private final static boolean ASCENDING=true, DESCENDING=false;

    public void sort(int[] a)
    {
        this.a=a;
        bitonicSort(0, a.length, ASCENDING);
    }

    private void bitonicSort(int lo, int n, boolean dir)
    {
        if (n>1)
        {
            int m=n/2;
            bitonicSort(lo, m, ASCENDING);
            bitonicSort(lo+m, m, DESCENDING);
            bitonicMerge(lo, n, dir);
        }
    }

    private void bitonicMerge(int lo, int n, boolean dir)
    {
        if (n>1)
        {
            int m=n/2;
            for (int i=lo; i<lo+m; i++)
                compare(i, i+m, dir);
            bitonicMerge(lo, m, dir);
            bitonicMerge(lo+m, m, dir);
        }
    }

    private void compare(int i, int j, boolean dir)
    {
        if (dir==(a[i]>a[j]))
            exchange(i, j);
    }

    private void exchange(int i, int j)
    {
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[j];
        a[j]=t;
    }

}
```

Maybe anyone has ever tried calculating complexity of this Sort algorithm and could either give an example of Costs and Time? or reference to understanding what costs and times should be attributed ?

P.S I'm new to this and do not properly understand how it should be "calculated", so feel free to give suggestions. Appreciate.

Comment: The number of compares should be the same, with only the number of swaps affected by best / worst case data patterns. You could put a static counter in the compare routine to determine complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To analyze recursive procedures, you need to write and solve a recurrence. Here, let `S(n)` be the number of comparisons to sort `n` elements and `M(n)` be the number of comparisons to merge `n` elements.

```
           S(1) = 0
for n > 1, S(n) = 2 S(n/2) + M(n)
           M(1) = 0
for n > 1, M(n) = 2 M(n/2) + n/2
```

We can use the Case 2 of [Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) to solve these.

```
M(n) = Theta(n log n)
S(n) = 2 S(n/2) + Theta(n log n) = Theta(n (log n)^2)
```

Answer (score 2):

@DavidEisenstat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259577/1593077) is correct, but - to make things simpler to see, suppose we replaced:

```
private void compare(int i, int j, boolean dir)
{
    if (dir==(a[i]>a[j]))
        exchange(i, j);
}
```

in your code with

```
private void compare(int i, int j, boolean dir)
{
     // assuming i < j
     int lower = min(a[i], a[j]);         
     int upper = max(a[i], a[j]);         
     a[i] = lower;
     a[j] = upper;
}
```

now the entire procedure has absolutely *no* branching; it's entirely non-adaptive and the best and worst case are the same. (Well, basically; I'm ignoring things like CPU branch prediction, and the need for a branch-free implementation of `min()` and `max()` and so on). This is one of the beautiful features of the bitonic sort, which makes it attractive for hardware implementations - and it makes its worst-case easier to analyze.